# How to disable Amazon Single Sign-on in Kindle Fire tablet

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

​I've two Amazon Kindle Fire tablets and i've an Amazon Prime Subscription.

I don't want to use the same Amazon Prime account in Fire tablet. Because my Contacts, Preferences, Calendar everything gets synced between. I don't want that.

I want to use separate Amazon accounts in each Fire tab and use a Complete Amazon Prime Subscription for Prime Video, Music and Kindle Apps in Fire. How can i make it possible ?

1.​ Amazon Account 3 - Has Prime Subscription

2. Amazon Fire HD 10 ( Amazon Account 1 with No Prime Subscription )

   ```
   Use Amazon Account 3 for Fire Apps - Prime Video, Music and Kindle
   ```
3. Amazon Fire HD 7 ( Amazon Account 2 with No Prime Subscription )

   ```
   Use Amazon Account 3 for Fire Apps - Prime Video, Music and Kindle
   ```

​I've tried ADB, to uninstall Amazon's own Prime Video app - com.amazon.avod and tried to install APK from the Google Play Store - com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient, so that i can configure the Prime Video with a different account. But the app is not getting uninstalled and if i try to install com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient, i'm getting PROVIDER CONFLICT error.

```
    pm uninstall --user 0 com.amazon.avod
    Success 
    pm install /storage/emulated/0/Download/com.amazon.avod.thirdpartyclient_2018-10-19.apk
    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
```

I can think of

1. ​Installing Stock Android in the Fire tabs, which will make things easy and better.
2. Disabling Single Sign on in Amazon Kindle Fire tab - which i have no idea how to.

Please can somebody shed some light on this.​